# How to prove the maximum possible number of elements of $S$ is $48$?

Tags: combinatorics

> Let set $S\subseteq \{1,2,3,\cdots,100\}$,for any two different $a,b\in S$,there exist postive integer $k$ and $c,d\in S(c<d)$,($c,d$ can equal to $a$ or $b$),such $$a+b=c^k\cdot d$$
>   show that
>   $$\max|S|=48$$

I have found this example is such it,and it is not easy to prove when $$S=\{1,2,3,4,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,\cdots79,81,83,85,87,89,91\}\Longrightarrow |S|=48$$
Because $a,b$ are odd(even),then 
$$4\le a+b\le 89+91$$
Let $c=2,d=\dfrac{a+b}{2^k}$

if $a$ odd,$b$ is even,then 
$$3\le a+b\le 95$$
take $c=1,k=1,d=a+b$
hold.But How to prove why the maximum the number is $48$?

Comment: You should try to dertermine which elements in $\{1,...,199\}$ can be write as $c^k \cdot d$ so you can keep all prime numbers with $c=1$ and $k=1$ then you have a min, after no idea for this time.

Comment: I think is in $\{3,4,5,\cdots,199\}$ can be wrirte as $c^k\cdot d$,can you find it other example,because maybe have lot of example such it

Comment: $14^2=196$ then at max c<14 then if you take $9^2 * 2 =162$ but $2<9$ so you can eliminate all impossible cases :)

Comment: is $c,d\in S$,@bof

Comment: @Shadock,yes.But you idea little ugly.

Comment: From where the 199 when the question is about 100? Now, if c =1, k could be any value and the only condition to comply with is: a+b=d, which may be fulfilled for every value of d picked in the range. It seems that c can not be 1 or 1 is not included in the original group.

Comment: Oh oups yes sorry you're right... can we consider $0^0=1$

Comment: There is an easy upper bound of 50: since 101 is prime, out of each of the pairs $\{1,100\},\{2,99\},\ldots,\{50,51\}$ you can have at most one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in [@YuvalFilmus](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1277/yuval-filmus)' comment, we have an upper bound of $50$ because we need to avoid a sum of $101$, so of all $50$ distinct pairs in range that sum to this value, we can have at most one of that pair.

However having observed that restriction, it seems that we can in fact select $50$ numbers as members of $S$, **giving $\max|S| = 50$ in contradiction to the claim**. All the odd numbers except $99$, and $2$.

$$\{1,2,3,5,7,9,11,...,95,97\}$$

Now for $a,b$ both odd, we take $c=2$, and $k$ as the multiplicity of $2$ as a factor of $a+b$, to leave an odd number in range as $d$. We know that $d$ is part of $S$ because $\frac{a+b}{2} < 97 = \max S$.

For $\{a,b\} = \{2,97\} $ we can take (for example) $c=9, k=1, d=11$

For any other sum involving $2$, we can take $c=a+b, k=1, d=1$.